# Block without variable

Tags: ruby, variables, block

I'm faced with a syntax that I don't quite understand. This is the code:

```
   config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors",:logger => (-> { Rails.logger }) do
      allow do
        origins '*'

        resource '/cors',
          :headers => :any,
          :methods => [:post],
          :credentials => true,
          :max_age => 0

        resource '*',
          :headers => :any,
          :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options, :head],
          :max_age => 0
      end
    end
```

After `do` in the first line, there is no variable declared as we will do in a regular block, for example:

```
array.each do |element| 
  puts element
end
```

How should I interpret the first example?

Comment: The given code example is very likely using BasicObject#instance_exec or #instance_eval which changes the meaning of self within the block passed to the method. This technique is often used for  making a DSL.

Comment: @iron_davior, you mean config.middleware.insert_before is using what you mention in the method definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block variables are useful when, while defining the block, you aren't certain what the used values are going to be. However, if you already have access to those values, you can use them directly instead of relying on the variables passed to a block.

Let me provide some very basic examples:

```
# run the following code

class CB
  def self.show_num
    yield
  end
end

CB.show_num do
  1
end
```

In case you don't know what values will be used, you make the block flexible i.e. have it expect an argument.

```
# run the following code

class CB
  CONSTA = 1
  CONSTB = 2

  def self.show_with_sign
    val = yield(CONSTA, CONSTB).round(2)
    "#{val}%"
  end
end

CB.show_with_sign do |num, den|
  100 * num.fdiv(den)
end
```

In the code you have shared, all the information is already present where the block is being declared. In simpler words, you already have the values to generate the output for the block. Thus it is handed off to the method as is, without any arguments.

Comment: What do you mean by *"all the information is already present where the block is being declared"*?

Comment: I mean that there isn't any missing information / value / variable that your intended output depends on.

Comment: This is a very confusing explanation. Block arguments are never "required". They are always optional and whether or not you _should_ include them is entirely dependent on the method implementation and your use case.

Comment: The answer uses examples to showcase how and why block arguments aren't always necessary thereby clarifying the OP's confusion, which is probably why it was accepted. But I've edited the word 'required' to 'useful' to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 3):

It is a block that takes no block variables, or a block to which block variables may be passed but are not used.

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory to pass block variables to the block:

```
▶ def helloer &cb
▷   puts cb.call
▷ end  
# => :helloer
▶ helloer { 'Hello, world' }
Hello, world
# => nil
```

Comment: Why would you get `:configure` as return value for defining `helloer`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary that a block has variables. Check this out, for example:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
array.each do
  puts "Hello"
end
# => Hello
# Hello
# Hello
```